# Setting default page for Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

In rails how to set the default page for controller. In my application I have a controller named "greet" which have two actions "welcome"
and "wishes". So while calling the welcome page like "localhost:3000/greet/welcome" is properly worked.

But My requirement is if I didn't
give the action name for that controller like "localhost:3000/greet", then it takes the default page associated for that controller only. How to do this
in rails 4.2. I tried to make an index action within greet controller. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hope you found the answer.

Comment: you can do :resources in routes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your **routes.rb** add line:

```
get '/greet' => 'greet#welcome'
```

you must also in folder `view` create folder `greet` and in this folder you have to create file `welcome.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 get '/greet', to: 'greet#welcome'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails work with REST concept. So, according to this when you just call `localhost:3000/greet` it will search `greet#index` method. Well, If you want to see any custom method while using`localhost:3000/greet`, you will need to write in file **config/routes.rb** like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'greet', :to => 'greet#welcome', :as => :greet
end
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :greet, controller: 'greet' do
    get 'welcome'
    get 'wishes'

    #Default resource routing
    get '/', to: 'greet#welcome'
  end
end
```